# Перебор родных свойств объекта

Tags: javascript

Привет. Не подскажите, как перебрать родные свойства объекта?

На странице есть несколько элементов с неким классом(пусть будет .my-class) и со всеми ними нужно произвести некие операции, например, удалить. Как это сделать? Без jQuery, разумеется.

Есть такой код:

```
nodes = document.querySelectorAll('.my-class');

for (var node in nodes) {
  if (nodes.hasOwnProperty(node)) {
    console.log(node, nodes[node]);
    nodes[node].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[node]);
  }
}
```

Но он перебирает не только сами элементы, но и свойство length, равное количеству найденных элементов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Цикл `for .. in ..` не подходит для перебора массивов, так как перебирает свойства объекта.

Исправленый вариант:

```
for(var i = 0, node = nodes[i]; i < nodes.length; i++, node = nodes[i]) {
    node.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Демо: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/xUUf3/

Comment: Хм.. видимо, я просто перепутал, изначально был вариант похожий на ваш:

    for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length-1; i <= len; i++) {
        console.log(nodes[i]);
        nodes[i].parentNode.removeChild(nodes[i]);
    }

Но посчитал, что это не "тру" т.к. думал, что nodes в данном случае именно объект, а не обычный массив. 
Спасибо.

Comment: не за что)

Answer (score 1):

Похоже это баг Хрома, но в вашем случае так и так `for in` не уместен, лучше:

```
for( var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++ ) { ... }

// или обратный while
var i = nodes.length;
while( i-- ){ ... }
```

Comment: Думаю, с for лучше будет. Спасибо.

Comment: В вашем случае `for от 0..n` вызовет ошибку, а вот обратный while нет, либо `for от (n-1)..0`

Comment: Оу, нет, все окей, перепутал.